# Use initWithHTML from NSAttributedString (OAExtensions)

Tags: ios, ipad, text, editor, nsattributedstring

I am using the Omni iOS **TextEditor** available @ github, and I want to use the initWithHTML method from NSAttributedString (OAExtensions), and use this method in the EditableFrame class,

but if I write [[**NSAttributedString** alloc] initWithHTML:string] this method is not found
and if I write [[**NSAttributedString (OAExtensions)** initWithHTML:string] I get a Syntax error

so how should this be done ?

Answer (score 2):

In line 76 of NSAttributedString-OAExtensions.m, there is an `#if 0` line that prevents `initWithHTML` from compiling. Remove that line and the corresponding `#endif` line and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have written the method name correctly and it does indeed exist, you have to `#import` the header file where the category is declared.

Comment: Yes I did import the header file, but how should the method call be written ? because the 2 ways I wrote above are not correct, and if I write [NSAttributedString alloc] only this does not contain the initWithHTML method, so I do not know how to use the method in the implementation of NSAttributedString (OAExtensions)

Comment: `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:string]` is correct. Why don't you show us your code in context, including the exact error message you get? And please provide a link to the library you are using.

Comment: this is the code

NSAttributedString *insertThis = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:text];

Comment: Link for the Framework
https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEdit

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE is:
-[NSConcreteAttributedString initWithHTML:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a68720
2011-04-18 18:32:41.929 TextEditor[60774:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteAttributedString initWithHTML:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a68720' *** Call stack at first throw:) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException' Program received signal:“SIGABRT”.